# Scaling views with ObjectAnimator... How to get real scaled width and heigh?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, objectanimator

I'm using ObjectAnimator class to scale some views:

```
    scaleX =  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 0.1f, MAX_SCALE);      
    scaleX.setDuration(animationTime);
    scaleX.setInterpolator(null);
    scaleY =  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 0.1f, MAX_SCALE);
    scaleY.setDuration(animationTime);
    scaleY.setInterpolator(null);
```

When the animation has finalized, I'm checking the width and the height of the view:

```
  scaleX.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Log.d("width",view.getWidth())
            Log.d("height",view.getHeight());
        }
   }
```

The problem is that the width and the height returned is very low... 145 and 154, and it has non sense, because the max and last scale factor applyed is 4, so as I can see in the screen the width and the heigh is munch higher than 150 or similar values.

How can I get the real width and heigh values of a view after using scales with ObjectAnimator?